# Безопасность chroot-окружения для мини-хостинга

Tags: chroot

На одной VPS делаю мини-хостинг - несколько пользовательских аккаунтов, у каждого свои сайты.

Чтобы разграничить доступ и не дать возможности свободно гулять по системе, сделал chroot для каждого из них, 
по мотивам однотипных статей ssh/sftp chroot, которых много на просторах инета. Сделал это для:

```
- Для работы по SSH нужно им дать возможность выполнять ТОЛЬКО: ls, cd, rm, mkdiv, cp, tar и подобные команды + делать дампы баз данных через mysqldump

- Для работы по SFTP нужно запереть пользователя в его дом. директории с его сайтами.
```

Но задался вопросом, насколько это безопасно, если кто-то попытается выйти за пределы chroot, то получат root-права 
и далее все вытекающие из этого последствия или не так все страшно?

Если не chroot (хотя кроме вопроса безопасности он меня вполне устраивает), то может лучше LXC, или это перебор для таких задач?

Подскажите пжл, только пжл не предлагайте простой способ настройки прав на директории и файлы без какого-либо доп. ограничения перемещения пользователей по системе.

А может я просто начитался страшилок и в плане моих задач SSH chroot вполне безопасен?

Comment: Чем простой способ настройки прав не угодил? Именно так и делают все "взрослые" shared-хостинги, без chroot.

Comment: Простой способ настройки прав не подходит тем, что крайне необходимо не дать возможность пользователю просматривать содержимое различных директорий в системе, даже через `ls`. Не встречал, либо крайне редко, чтобы на shared-хостинге было позволено гулять по системе даже  в режиме просмотра.

Comment: Все shared-хостинги, которыми я пользовался, позволяли гулять по системе. В этом нет ничего небезопасного: пароли и приватные ключи скрыты по умолчанию, а всё остальное прятать чаще всего нет смысла.

Comment: Из потенциально секретных кандидатов на прятание можно отметить логи (/var/log), dmesg, список процессов (см. proc hidepid) и какие-нибудь настройки безопасности apache/nginx, но это всё индивидуально и не всегда секретно. // По теме вопроса из ненастроенного chroot можно легко сбежать [обыкновенным "cd /proc/1/cwd"](https://serverfault.com/questions/363091), например. (Как дела с SSH chroot, не в курсе, не пользовался)