# Cделать chroot без root

Tags: linux, chroot

В продолжение моей этой темы [Безопасность chroot-окружения для мини-хостинга](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/953396/%D0%91%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BD%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D1%8C-chroot-%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D0%B4%D0%BB%D1%8F-%D0%BC%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B8-%D1%85%D0%BE%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B8%D0%BD%D0%B3%D0%B0)

Как можно сделать chroot без root, т.е, чтобы если пользователь и вырвался из chroot - не получил root? А точнее без root он не вырвется из chroot.

Answer (score 0):

chroot принимает параметры. Добавь `userspec=<имя пользователя>:<имя группы пользователей>` - он сменит пользователя перед выполнением команды.

Comment: А как это сделать во время начала SSH сессии chroot-пользователя, т.е. подменять его? - в целях того, чтобы не дать ему вылезти под root.

Comment: @Александр ssh сам умеет отправлять пользователя в chroot  http://docs.mirocow.com/doku.php?id=system:chroot_ssh и разумеется пользователь войдет в систему под собой. И рутом он сможет после этого стать только если найдет какой нибудь баг ядре или программе. достпутной в его корне и имеющей suid бит (не оставляйте ему таких программ)

Comment: @Mike Везде пишут как просто и легко вырваться из chroot и стать root со всеми вытекающими. Для этого существует масса вариантов. При этом chroot-пользователь входит под собой, не под рутом?

Comment: @Александр "Везде" - это где конкретно ? И сама постановка вопроса не верна. место положения корневой папки, видимой пользователем и его эффективный uid никак между собой не связаны. Поэтому нельзя утверждать, что выход из chroot приведет к получению прав root, так же как и неверно обратное утверждение, что получение прав рута позволит выйти из chroot

Comment: @Mike https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Z9l4naJzVgg&t=2705s   
https://github.com/earthquake/chw00t/blob/master/Presentations/Balazs_Bucsay_Hacktivity2015_chw00t.pdf

Comment: @Александр О чем я и сказал в своем первом посте. Это возможно при наличии багов в ядре. И да, баги периодически продолжают находится. Но если вы присмотритесь внимательнее к последней таблице в той "презентации", то обнаружите, что подверженные тем атакам версии ядер linux 10 летней давности. И поверьте, за это время от тех дыр не осталось и следа.

Comment: @Александр Так что все что вы можете сделать - это отправить пользователя в chroot. Следить за всеми выходящими бюллетенями по безопасности и вовремя обновлять ядро или устанавливать экстренные патчи. то же касается вообще всего софта в системе